# Open Visual Studio 2008 Project in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio

I have created a project using Visual Studio 2008 and .NET Framework 2.0.

Now I want to open it in Visual Studio 2005 (.NET Framework 2.0).

When I try to open the solution in Visual Studio 2005 it is showing an error as "It is created using the Higher versions".

So is there any way I could open the project in Visual Studio 2005?

Or should I redo the entire project in Visual Studio 2005?

Please help me out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439061/visual-studio-2008-and-visual-studio-2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439061/visual-studio-2008-and-visual-studio-2005)

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the solution file and project files (not recommended, but you can). If it's a csproj file, change the line

```
<ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
```

to

```
<ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
```

If it's the sln file, change:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
```

to

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 9.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help!

Where can I change the Product Version?

Comment: If you open the .csproj file in notepad, take a look in the PropertyGroup section under Project. It's in there.

Comment: I changed it but even then it is not getting opened. What should I do?
Is there any way I could do this?
Please help me out, my entire project is ready but I have to open it in VS 2005. That's the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the project file instead of the solution file.  Otherwise just create a new VS2005 project and add all the files and folders from the VS2008 project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Visual Studio Project Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vspc), a handy tool to convert between most versions of Visual Studio (VS 2002, 2003, 2005 and 2008).

But unfortunately, converting .NET projects is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same problem.
Modifying the .sln file and .csproj file by notepad is the solution.
If want to know more about the file format, we can create a simple project both in VS2005 and VS2008, then compare the project files.